# Import es6 module in chrome extension mv 3 background script with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, babeljs

I'm new at building a **Chrome extension mv3**. Now I'm creating an **extension** using **Typescript** as my main language. I've tried to import **Es6 modules**, but when I loaded the extension, Chrome says that "**Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined**".

Here's my project structure

```
|   .babelrc
|   manifest.json
|   package.json
|   tsconfig.json
|   webpack.config.js
|
+---public
|   +---html
|   |       index.html
|   |       popup.html
|   |
|   +---js
|   |       background.d.ts
|   |       background.js
|   |       background.js.map
|   |       background.utils.d.ts
|   |       background.utils.js
|   |       background.utils.js.map
|   |       index.html
|   |       main.js
|   |       popup.d.ts
|   |       popup.js
|   |       popup.js.map
|   |
|   \---styles
|           popup.css
|
\---src
    |   background.ts
    |   background.utils.ts
    |   popup.ts
    |
    \---@types
        \---background
                index.d.ts
```

My manifest.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "./public/js/background.js",
    "persitent": true
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "./public/html/popup.html"
  },
  "minimum_chrome_version": "92",
  "permissions": [
    "management",
    "scripting",
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest",
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*.nytimes.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "./public/js/popup.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",                                  
    "module": "commonjs",                                
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],                                 
    "sourceMap": true,                            
    "outDir": "./public/js",                      
    "sourceRoot": "./src",                        
    "esModuleInterop": true,                      
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,     
    "strict": true,                               
    "skipLibCheck": true                          
  }
}
```

In my background.utils.ts file:

```
const myFunction = ()=>{}
export default myFunction
```

In my background.ts file:

```
import myFunction from './background.utils/'
```

But Chromes says that export is not defined even though I've tried serveral methods on Internet like add "type": "module" into the mainifest.json file or remote "module":"commonjs" in tsconfig.json file.

Do you guys have any idea why this happens?

Looking forward to receiving you guys' answers

Thank you so much.

Comment: ...and so did you discover a solution?

Answer (score 4):

You already tried to insert into manifest, "type: module"?

```
"background": {
  "service_worker": "./public/js/background.js",
  "type": "module"
},
```

Comment: yes, I've already done that

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this is what worked for me with v3 of the manifest.

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "ES6",
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "types": [
      "chrome"
    ],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "A Chrome Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "bla bla",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "dist/popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "dist/assets/images/icon16.png",
            "48": "dist/assets/images/icon48.png",
            "128": "dist/assets/images/icon128.png"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [ ... ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "dist/background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "host_permissions": [ ... ]
}
```

The things that need to be locked down are:

- `ES6` for both `target` and `module` in `tsconfig.json` and
- `"type": "module"` in `manifest.json`'s `"background"`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try `"module": "amd"`?

I've faced similar issue a while ago, and I guess that was the solution: as "amd" removed all the "exports", if i remember correctly. Let me know if that does not help, I'll take a deeper look at the project.

Another option was to run a stripper and remove the exports, but that sounds unnecessary.